# How to get XML parse of a tree to a string?

Tags: stanford-nlp

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
```

I want to get an XML representation of the parse tree into a string. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string s contains the XML output of the parse tree"

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
tree.indentedXMLPrint( writer, false);
String s = stringWriter.toString()
```